# Send event to Google Analytics not working using Google Tag Manager

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to implement Google Tag Manager to track the user interacts with my app, I have followed the guide from [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/ua#send-events) but I faced some issues.

This is my Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String CONTAINER_ID = "GTM-TRFZVD5";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TagManager tagManager = TagManager.getInstance(this);
    tagManager.setVerboseLoggingEnabled(true);
    PendingResult<ContainerHolder> pendingResult =
            tagManager.loadContainerPreferNonDefault(CONTAINER_ID, R.raw.gtm_trfzvd5);

    pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContainerHolder>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull ContainerHolder containerHolder) {
            ContainerHolderSingleton.setContainerHolder(containerHolder);
            Container container = containerHolder.getContainer();
            if(!containerHolder.getStatus().isSuccess()){
                Log.e(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Failure loading container");
                return;
            }
            ContainerLoadedCallback.registerCallbackForContainer(container);
            containerHolder.setContainerAvailableListener(new ContainerLoadedCallback());
            startAnotherActivity();
        }
    }, 2, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}

private void startAnotherActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is the Activity that user will interact

```
public class AnotherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    GTMUtils.pushOpenScreenEvent(getApplicationContext(), AnotherActivity.class.getSimpleName());

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GTMUtils.pushClickButtonEvent(getApplicationContext(),
                    "btn");

        }
    });
}
```

And these are two methods to push the event to Google Analytics

```
public static void pushOpenScreenEvent(Context context, String screenName){
    DataLayer dataLayer = TagManager.getInstance(context).getDataLayer();
    dataLayer.push(DataLayer.mapOf("event", "openScreen", "screenName", screenName));
}


public static void pushClickButtonEvent(Context context, String btnEventName){
    DataLayer dataLayer = TagManager.getInstance(context).getDataLayer();
    dataLayer.push(DataLayer.mapOf("event", "videoPlay", "videoName", btnEventName));

}
```

I copied exactly from Google Guide but I when I ran the app, it only pushed the first event ("open screen") and the click button didn't send anything.
So did I do something wrong?

Comment: Did you set up a tag in the Google Tag Manager interface that is triggered by the `videoPlay` event?

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that I have to wait for a while for Google Analytics update.